# Writing a TinyMCE custom plugin with java based logic

Tags: javascript, java, sphinx4

I am a newbie in plugin development, and with regards to a school project I am working on, I am required to develop a voice to speech functionality which allows a user to speak input into a text editor, in this case I am constrained to the TinyMCE editor. I was given an already well developed java speech recognition library to work with, by name of CMU Sphinx- sphinx4.

So now, my problem. Sphinx4 is a java library and it contains all the logic I need to use to create the plugin. But with TinyMCE, I am restricted to writing the plugin in javascript. I tried writing a simple demo, with no success in getting the plugin to work. Here are the code snippets
1. Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea',
        plugins: 'voiceDictation',
        toolbar: 'voiceDictation'
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea>Testing voiceDictation</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Dictate.java

   ```
   package javapackage;
   import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
   import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer;

   import java.io.IOException;

   public class Dictate {
   public static LiveSpeechRecognizer dictate() throws IOException {
       Configuration configuration = new Configuration();



    configuration.setAcousticModelPath
    ("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
   configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
   configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");

   LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
   recognizer.startRecognition(true);
   return recognizer;
   }
   }
   ```
3. plugin.js

   ```
   import _ from 'lodash';

   const plugin = (editor) => {
   editor.addButton('voiceDictation', {
   text: 'voiceDictation',
   icon: false,
   onclick: () => {
   var recognizer = Packages.javapackage.Dictate.dictate;
   var result = recognizer.getHypothesis();

       editor.windowManager.open({
           title: 'voiceDictation plugin',
           body: [
               { type: 'textbox', name: {result} }
           ],


   })
   }
   })
   };

   export default plugin;
   ```
4. Index.js

   ```
   import plugin from './plugin';

   tinymce.PluginManager.add('voiceDictation', plugin);
   ```

Any help, no matter how minimal would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Java and javascript are very different languages and you rarely can use java libraries from javascript unless you set a server which will run java library and contact it over network. Javascript in a browser has very limited capabilities to interact with other software. For your task you can use javascript speech recognition library, for example

[Chrome Web Speech API](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/speechapi.html) - works only in Chrome

[Dictate.js](https://kaljurand.github.io/dictate.js/) - works in Firefox too, but requires a server somewhere. Will not work in some browsers anyway.

You can search for others.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. One thing I'd like to note is the fact that I'm restricted to using CMU Sphinx 4